# Show one div and hide any other that are open

Tags: jquery, jsp

I'm trying to show one div at a time so when button is pressed it shows that div and hides the others if any of them are visible. I've tried few examples but failed. The code below is hiding all the shown divs on one click.

```
<% for(var i = 0; i < 3; i++){ %>
        <button class="but<%= i %>" >Show Skeetchpad</button>
        <div id="p<%=i%>" ></div>

                    <script>
                        $(document).ready(function(){
                         $("#p<%= i %>").hide();
                            $(".but<%= i %>").click(function(){

                                if ($.trim($(this).text()) === 'Show Sketchpad') {
                                    $(this).parent().siblings().hide();
                                    $("#p<%= i%>").load("sketch.jsp");
                                    $("#p<%= i %>").show("slow");                                       
                                    $(this).text('Hide Sketchpad').css("font-weight","bold");
                                } else {
                                    $(this).text('Show Sketchpad').css("font-weight","normal");
                                    location.reload(false);
                                    $("#p<%= i %>").hide("slow");
                                }
                                return false; 
                            }); 
                        });
                    </script>    
                    <hr>
                    <%
                        }
                    %>
```

Comment: You need to create a simple, working demo for us. It doesn't have to be your exact project, just something that gets the point across. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Is it because your button text is "Show Skeetchpad" so this will always evaluate as false - `if ($.trim($(this).text()) === 'Show Sketchpad') {`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the following snippet in your button handler.

```
<%-- Get the class name of the button that is clicked --%>
var buttonClass = $(this).attr('class');
<%-- Get the div ID corresponding to the button clicked.
E.g. if the button clicked is but3, the corresponding div that needs to be shown
is p3. The remaining ones should be hidden
 --%>
var divId = "p" + buttonClass[buttonClass.length - 1];
<%-- Hide all the divs the IDs of which start with a 'p' --%>
$("div[id^=p]").not(divId).hide();
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
$('button').on('click',function() {
  var c = '.'+$(this).attr('class');
  $('div').not(c).hide();
  $(c).show();
})
```

```css
div {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="div1">div1</button>
<button class="div2">div2</button>
<button class="div3">div3</button>
<div class="div1">div1</div>
<div class="div2">div2</div>
<div class="div3">div3</div>
```